# Malfunction of semctl() - bug in libc?

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, semaphore, libc

There is something alarming in `semctl()` functioning when it is called inside the shared library. Values returned for `IPC_STAT` command are incorrect. Precisely **uid**, **gid** and **mode** fields. There is no problem when the function is called from the standalone program. In such case all values are correct. What is important in my case, I use semaphores exactly in the same way in the shared library and in the standalone program.

Below you can find a problematic code:

```
static int sem_check( int semid ) {
    union semun semdata;
    semdata.buf = (struct semid_ds*)malloc( sizeof(struct semid_ds) );
    memset( semdata.buf, 0, sizeof(struct semid_ds) );

    int rc = semctl( semid, 0, IPC_STAT, semdata );

    if( rc==0 ) {
        if( semdata.buf->sem_perm.uid==0 && semdata.buf->sem_perm.gid==999 && semdata.buf->sem_perm.mode==0660 ) {
            printf("semaphore OK");
        } else {
            printf( "semaphore BAD: uid: %hd, gid: %hd, mode: %ho", semdata.buf->sem_perm.uid, semdata.buf->sem_perm.gid, semdata.buf->sem_perm.mode );
        }
    }
    else {
        printf( "semctl() error: %d", rc );
    }

    return rc;
}
```

In my case, the semaphore is created with uid=0, gid=999 and mode=0660. When I call above function from the standalone program I got the same values ("semaphore OK" message). When I call it from the shared library I got uid=0, gid=0 and mode=7072 ("semaphore BAD" message). Of course in both cases the process has read permissions for the semaphore and there is no talk about `semctl()` error.

Is it possible I found a bug in the standard C library?

**My working environment:**

- Linux Debian Wheezy,
- libc v2.13,
- gcc v4.7.2.

Comment: This is too few information... Please provide code, expected result and actual result. Wild guess: do you check the return value of semctl()? Maybe the call fails and you observe uninitialized values

Comment: *Shoud I know about something "special" to use semaphores inside shared libraries?* There's **nothing** special about using semaphores from code in a shared library.  Post your code.  Right now the question will wind up closed if you don't.

Comment: I made a test using `semctl()` with `SEM_STAT` command and a result is the same. Call from a plain `main()` function returns correct values. The same code run inside a shared object returns some random values.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. When creating a shared library, a `gcc -shared` command must be used instead of `ld --shared`. It is caused by the wrong linking of common shared libraries while creating the subject one. This is a known bug, link below.

https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=20489